# wildcard git error

Tags: git

How can I correct the following error:

```
There are no candidates for merging among the refs that you just fetched.
Generally this means that you provided a wildcard refspec which had no
matches on the remote end.
```

This happens when I pull from origin to my local branch using git.

What can I do?

Comment: whatt command are you giving?

Comment: Looking at your .git/config file might help to determine the problem. Can you paste it here?

Comment: A little more context please?

Comment: tell us the command that are you using and the output of 'git status'